# Win7 Python load data into MySQL Warning: Data truncated for column 'tweet_id' at row 1

Tags: python, mysql, windows-7

I can load the dataset into MySQL, but the data I get in MySQL are different with the original.

WIN7+Python+MySQL

The original:

```
639468190716727296  631120309   1441296072  Twitter Web Client  @minh0pls i thought it was a new member at first too    .0  0.0
639468197171716096  313657155   1441296073  Facebook    Friday Magic Playing Cards Review http://t.co/pD82WN20xy    0.0 0.0
639468192587489280  144491670   1441296072  Instagram   Old is gold \U0001F3C8 \U2728 \U0001F495 I missed you guys BIG TIME even tho I didn't really show it \U0001F60C \U0001F618 \U0001F646 @ Pepperonis @ \U2026 https://t.co/EyErVHmfmA 0.0 0.0
639468194210578432  285436516   1441296072  Google  Many healthy food options for back to school TheChronicleHerald ca http://t.co/LMHxgEgVoM   0.0 0.0
639468194604937216  2914395021  1441296072  Twitter Web Client  @hxcates sasori dumps half of her cosmetics into the trash and sakura just looks on sadly cause she doesnt even know if they were important 0.0 0.0
639468195674324992  129158783   1441296073  Twitter for Android @WeekhengBHS    0.0 0.0
```

The data I get:

```
639468190716727296 302 0 000 other facebook followers here http://t.co/bBng5nEhK0 Happy t 096 gold coins http://t.co/pp8BmXECif #ipad #ipadgames #gameinsight   0.0 0.0
639472384072814592  166039458   1441297071  The Tribez for iPad I've harvested 357 of food http://t.co/pp8BmXECif #ipad #ipadgames #gameinsight 0.0 0.0
639472388330024960  578347890   1441297072  T 0E-9 165.000000000
639468192587489280 144491670 1441296072 Instagram Old is gold U0001F3C8 U2728 U0001F495 I missed you guys BIG TIME even tho I didn't really show it U0001F60C U0001F618 U0001F646 @ Pepperonis @ U2026 https://t.co/EyErVHmfmA 0E-9 0E-9
639468194210578432 285436516 1441296072 Google Many healthy food options for back to school TheChronicleHerald ca http://t.co/LMHxgEgVoM 0E-9 0E-9
639468194604937216 2914395021 1441296072 Twitter Web Client @hxcates sasori dumps half of her cosmetics into the trash and sakura just looks on sadly cause she doesnt even know if they were important 0E-9 0E-9
```

Comment: That's too bad, but what do you expect us to be help you with? You haven't explain how you're loading this data, what your table structure is, etc...

Comment: What is the column definition for `tweet_id`? It looks like it's too small.

Comment: I use :sql="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'G:/Dataset/singhose-election-week-no-retweets-mysql-import/singhose-election-week-no-retweets-mysql-import.txt' INTO TABLE shCleanedTweets FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'" to load the txt

Comment: tweet_id BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,   the column definition for twitter_id